# regular expression to match paired double quotation mark

Tags: regex

I have a string like:

```
I say “hello “world” ”foo“ bar”
```

note: `“` is not `"`.

How can I get the string surrounded by first paired double quotation:

```
hello “world” ”foo“ bar
```

Comment: Is there any reason why "foo" has `”` and `“` inverted? Can that happen randomly in your string? Also what programming language are you targeting?

Comment: No, `“` and `”` appear in order. No programming language, just a regular expression. you can test it by  `grep`.

Comment: You have nested, balanced `“` characters and `grep`'s regex engine cannot deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

(?<=“)(\w*?)(?=”)

This uses the Look Behind and Look Ahead in combo and captures everything in between.

The output is world

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VCFpsm/1)

Comment: thanks, but my expectation is `hello “world” ”foo“ bar`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misunderstood your question.
This should clean up mismatched curly quotes in the text fragment you provided.

`\W?(\w* )(“\w*”)|(”\w*“)( \w*)\W?`

Subsitute

`$1$2$3$4`

hello “world” ”foo“ bar

[Link to Demo of Answer](https://regex101.com/r/a6DbTO/1)